# Unable to set minimum duration for video recording in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-video-player

I used the code below to set  minimum duration for video recording, but it is not working. I have tested it on Android 2.2 and Android 2.3.3

```
intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.durationLimit", 60);
```

What is a correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I use

intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, 60);

Comment: Please expand your answer.